# Proof of existence of trace map $T:H^1(\mathbb{R}^n_+) \to H^{\frac 12}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ not using the Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace

I'm looking for a proof of the existence of the trace map $T:H^1(\mathbb{R}^n_+) \to H^{\frac 12}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ which **does not** use the Fourier transform.

In particular, I want to prove the following inequality without using Fourier methods
$$|u(x,0)|_{H^{\frac 12}} \leq C\lVert{u}\rVert_{H^1}$$
for appropriately smooth functions which then can be extended by density.

Does anyone have a source for this? Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, what is your definition of $|\cdot |_{H^{1/2}}$ (without appealing to the Fourier Transform)?

Comment: @Jose27 It's the Slobodeckij seminorm defined as integral over the boundary (eg. similar to the first equation in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61296/sobolev-slobodeckij-spaces-for-p-infinity).

Comment: Check out Leoni's book. Chapter 15. http://www.amazon.com/Course-Sobolev-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821847686